# Getting min and max Dates from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

How do I get the min and max Dates from a dataframe's major axis?

```
           value
Date                                           
2014-03-13  10000.000 
2014-03-21   2000.000 
2014-03-27   2000.000 
2014-03-17    200.000 
2014-03-17      5.000 
2014-03-17     70.000 
2014-03-21    200.000 
2014-03-27      5.000 
2014-03-27     25.000 
2014-03-31      0.020 
2014-03-31     12.000 
2014-03-31      0.022
```

Essentially I want a way to get the min and max dates, i.e. `2014-03-13` and `2014-03-31`. I tried using `numpy.min` or `df.min(axis=0)`, I'm able to get the min or max value but that's not what I want

Answer (score 139, accepted):

'Date' is your index so you want to do,

```
print (df.index.min())
print (df.index.max())

2014-03-13 00:00:00
2014-03-31 00:00:00
```

Comment: Pandas gets more intuitive the more you use it.

Comment: I thought I had set_index to the datetime field, but alas I forgot to reassign it!  Should get these back in datetimes of course.

Comment: this assumes your df is indexed by date

Answer (score 71):

```
min(df['some_property'])
max(df['some_property'])
```

The built-in functions work well with Pandas Dataframes.

Comment: this didn't work for me

Answer (score 6):

Use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) to determine the minimum and maximum value in one line:

```
In [5]: df['Date'].agg(['min', 'max'])
Out[5]: 
min    2014-03-13
max    2014-03-31
```

If your desired column is in the index, you have to reset the index first:

```
df.reset_index()['Date'].agg(['min', 'max'])
```