# Finding the count, earliest date and latest date for each name in Python

Tags: python

Suppose if I have a data like the following,with Name, class and Date

```
Name    class   Date
A   7th grade   1/1/2016
A   7th grade   1/2/2016
A   7th grade   1/3/2016
A   7th grade   1/4/2016
A   7th grade   1/5/2016
A   7th grade   1/6/2016
A   7th grade   1/7/2016
B   8th grade   1/8/2016
B   8th grade   1/9/2016
B   8th grade   1/10/2016
C   9th grade   1/11/2016
C   9th grade   1/12/2016
C   9th grade   1/13/2016
C   9th grade   1/14/2016
C   9th grade   1/15/2016
C   9th grade   1/16/2016
C   9th grade   1/17/2016
C   9th grade   1/18/2016
C   9th grade   1/19/2016
C   9th grade   1/20/2016
C   9th grade   1/21/2016
C   9th grade   1/22/2016
```

I am looking for a output which would give me the count of values for each name, their respective grade and the earliest date and the latest date. My output would be,

```
Name grade   count earlydate latestdate
A   7thgrade   7    1/1/2016  1/7/2016
B   8th grade  3    1/8/2016  1/10/2016
C   9th grade  12   1/11/2016 1/22/2016
```

I am able to find the counts of each name by,

```
data.groupby('name','grade').count()
or
data.groupby('name','grade').size()
```

But not able to find the early date and latest date inside the date column.

Can anybody help me in dng this?

Comment: What kind of database are you using ? Try using Joins, and MIN/MAX functions in sql

Comment: I have this as a python dataframe . Need to do this in python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178129/getting-min-and-max-dates-from-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @clemkoa Thanks for the link. but in that link, the dates are as index and not as column and also doesn't return a result like that I want. I want a dataframe here, which would give those details as shown

Comment: ok so maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024797/max-and-min-date-in-pandas-groupby  ?

Comment: @clemkoa Thanks! this works

Comment: Ok I'll try to post it as an answer then, so we can close the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Max and Min date in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024797/max-and-min-date-in-pandas-groupby)

Something like this maybe:

```
data.groupby('name','grade').agg({'date' : [np.min, np.max]}).count()
```