# Finding min and max of date column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am struggling with finding the max and min of date column in my dataset.

Below is my dataset:

```
customer_final['tran_date']

0       2014-02-28
1       2014-02-27
2       2014-02-24
3       2014-02-24
4       2014-02-23
           ...    
23048   2011-01-25
23049   2011-01-25
23050   2011-01-25
23051   2011-01-25
23052   2011-01-25
```

> As clearly we can see in the dataset we have data between 2011-01-25
>   to 2014-02-28.

But executing the below-mentioned code is giving me the wrong output.

```
print(customer_final['tran_date'].max())
print(customer_final['tran_date'].min())

2014-12-02 00:00:00
2011-01-02 00:00:00
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: Posting raw data.

```
transaction_id  cust_id tran_date   prod_subcat_code    prod_cat_code   Qty Rate    Tax total_amt   Store_type
0   80712190438 270351  28-02-2014  1   1   -5  -772    405.300 -4265.300   e-Shop
1   29258453508 270384  27-02-2014  5   3   -5  -1497   785.925 -8270.925   e-Shop
2   51750724947 273420  24-02-2014  6   5   -2  -791    166.110 -1748.110   TeleShop
3   93274880719 271509  24-02-2014  11  6   -3  -1363   429.345 -4518.345   e-Shop
4   51750724947 273420  23-02-2014  6   5   -2  -791    166.110 -1748.110   TeleShop
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
23048   94340757522 274550  25-01-2011  12  5   1   1264    132.720 1396.720    e-Shop
23049   89780862956 270022  25-01-2011  4   1   1   677 71.085  748.085 e-Shop
23050   85115299378 271020  25-01-2011  2   6   4   1052    441.840 4649.840    MBR
23051   72870271171 270911  25-01-2011  11  5   3   1142    359.730 3785.730    TeleShop
23052   77960931771 271961  25-01-2011  11  5   1   447 46.935  493.935 TeleShop
```

Edit 2: Datatypes of all the columns in the DF.

```
transaction_id               int64
cust_id                      int64
tran_date           datetime64[ns]
prod_subcat_code             int64
prod_cat_code                int64
Qty                          int64
Rate                         int64
Tax                        float64
total_amt                  float64
Store_type                  object
Unnamed: 10                 object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178129/getting-min-and-max-dates-from-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Is your column of type datetime?

Comment: Yes sir! But no luck.

Comment: Try to get `customer_final['tran_date'].max(). dt.day` at the max position and see if your datetime type is correct.

Comment: @coc018 Yes, it's dtype is `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: Perhaps the day is on the second place. That's why ist getting the right results. Try this as well: `pd.to_datetime(customer_final['tran_date')).max()`

Comment: @coco18 it's also giving the same result : `Timestamp('2014-12-02 00:00:00')`.

Comment: Did you try to get the day of the max?

Comment: @coco18 Yes. I tried to get the day for every date using `dt.day`. It's picking the correct day. But while attempting the do so on the max date using `customer_final['tran_date'].max(). dt.day` it's giving error: `'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'`.

Comment: Yes, but you can get it with `loc[] ` only to see which day and month returns.

Comment: before converting to DateTime specify the format `pd.to_datetime(...,format='%Y-%m-%d')` then call your min and max.

Comment: @Datanovice It's giving some weird error: `time data '12/2/2014' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'`

Comment: The change the `-` with `/`

Comment: can you post your raw data?

Comment: Was your data sorted by *tran_date* before running `customer_final['tran_date']` that you post above? If not, do so with `sort_values` and report back. Also, please post `customer_final.dtypes`.

Comment: Yes @Parfait, upon sorting the column I can see the values are as returned by Python. But, upon doing so manually in Excel I can see my data is for the date range 2011-01-25 to 2014-02-28.

Comment: So, is your question resolved in Python pandas? Specifically, do dates `2014-12-02` and `2011-01-02` show after sorting: `customer_final = customer_final.sort_values(by='tran_date', ascending = False)`

Comment: No @Parfait. Inspecting the data set manually I can see, I have data available for date range  `2011-01-25` to `2014-02-28`. But upon applying sort values on the respective column I can see the data is between `2011-01-02` and `2014-12-02`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have your dates (in an input file) formatted with
various ways.

One of your comments contains `Timestamp('2014-12-02 00:00:00')`,
so I see that you have *%Y-%m-%d* formatting (probably in most cases),
but in another place you have written `time data '12/2/2014'`, so at least
in some rows you have *%d/%m/%Y* formatting.

Bring your input to order. You can't have dates formatted in 2
different formattings.

## Edit

I performed the following experiment:

As the source data I used a part of your raw data (first 2 and last 2 rows),
with additional row (No 3) with different date formatting,
stored as a string variable:

```
  transaction_id cust_id tran_date prod_subcat_code prod_cat_code Qty Rate Tax total_amt Store_type
3       93274880719 271509  24-02-2014  11  6   -3  -1363   429.345 -4518.345   e-Shop
4       51750724947 273420  23-02-2014  6   5   -2  -791    166.110 -1748.110   TeleShop
40      51750724947 273420  12/2/2014   6   5   -2  -791    166.110 -1748.110   TeleShop
23048   94340757522 274550  25-01-2011  12  5   1   1264    132.720 1396.720    e-Shop
23049   89780862956 270022  25-01-2011  4   1   1   677     71.085  748.085     e-Shop'''
```

Note that the initial row has some spaces at the beginning, to provide
the empty column name for the index column.

Then I defined the following date parsing function (`import re` required),
to be used soon:

```
def dPars(txt):
    if re.match(r'\d{2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}', txt):
        return pd.to_datetime(txt, format='%d-%m-%Y')
    if re.match(r'\d{2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}', txt):
        return pd.to_datetime(txt, format='%d/%m/%Y')
    return txt
```

I read the above content, with the above date converter function:

```
customer_final = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True,
    index_col=0, parse_dates=['tran_date'], date_parser=dPars)
```

I printed *tran_date* column - `print(customer_final.tran_date)` - getting

```
3       2014-02-24
4       2014-02-23
40      2014-02-12
23048   2011-01-25
23049   2011-01-25
Name: tran_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

so all dates have been parsed as they should be.

I printed min / max dates - `print(customer_final['tran_date'].min(), customer_final['tran_date'].max())` - getting correct result:

```
2011-01-25 00:00:00 2014-02-24 00:00:00
```

Maybe you should base your code on my experiment (in your code replace
`io.StringIO(txt)` with your input file name).

Note also that if you have some input row formatted as `12/2/2014` then
*12* is the **month** number and *2* is the **day** number (US date format),
whereas other rows have the day number first.

Comment: I have tried different date formats to check there exist any problem within the data set.

Comment: If original field was already a datetime as [OP comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588564/finding-min-and-max-of-date-column-in-pandas#comment107190321_60588564), formatting cannot be the issue as mixed types are not allowed with this type. It is highly probable OP simply did not sort the data.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you have two issues: 1) viewing abbreviated data and 2) viewing unsorted data.

You claim: *As clearly we can see in the dataset we have data between 2011-01-25 to 2014-02-28.* However, Pandas is abbreviating your ***unsorted*** data, omitting *many* rows of your 23k row data frame with ellipsis: `...`. Hence, this manual inspection of dates you cite are only from the head and tail of the unordered data that will not match `min` and `max` values.

```
customer_final['tran_date']

# 0       2014-02-28       # <---- HEAD OF UNSORTED DATA
# 1       2014-02-27
# 2       2014-02-24
# 3       2014-02-24
# 4       2014-02-23
#            ...           # <---- OMITTED VALUES OF UNSORTED DATA 
# 23048   2011-01-25
# 23049   2011-01-25
# 23050   2011-01-25
# 23051   2011-01-25
# 23052   2011-01-25       # <---- TAIL OF UNSORTED DATA
```

You can remove omission of rows with `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)` but you may overwhelm yourself showing 23k+ values that are not sorted.

Therefore, those `min` and `max` are not wrong. To double check, actually sort your data and then print the column out or its head and tail. Doing so, the aggregate figures should match accordingly.

```
# SORT DATA FRAME IN DESCENDING ORDER BY tran_date
customer_final = customer_final.sort_values(by='tran_date', ascending = False)

# VIEW ALL DATA (ABBREVIATED UNLESS YOU CHANGE SETTING)
customer_final['tran_date']

# VIEW FIRST VALUES (DEFAULT TO 5)
customer_final['tran_date'].head(5)

# VIEW LAST VALUES (DEFAULT TO 5)
customer_final['tran_date'].tail(5)
```